# Remove outside double quotes from list of jinja strings

Tags: for-loop, jinja2, string-formatting, double-quotes, dbt

I'm formatting & appending strings to a list but the ref() function (used in dbt) isn't a string so I need to remove the outside quotes while retaining the inner single quotes.

I've attempted to chain strip() and replace() but neither are solving the problem.

Current code:

```
{% for result in results_list %}
    {% set result = "ref('{}')".format(result) %}
    {{ ref_format_results.append(result) }}
{% endfor %}

{% do log(ref_format_results, info=true) %}
```

Current output:

```
["ref('model_a')","ref('model_b')","ref('model_c')"]
```

Desired output:

```
[ref('model_a'),ref('model_b'),ref('model_c')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a string, which needs to be delimited somehow, and will always show outer quotes when printed/logged.

If you're templating those values into another file or string, then you'll already have what you want.

```
{% for r in ref_format_results %}
select * from {{ "{{" ~ r ~ "}}" }};
{% endfor %}
```

will produce:

```
select * from {{ ref('model_a') }};
select * from {{ ref('model_b') }};
select * from {{ ref('model_c') }};
```

But more importantly, why set result to a string in the first place? Are you trying to delay the execution of the `ref()` macro? If not, this will work just fine, to give you a list of evaluated refs (which are Relations):

```
{% for result in results_list %}
    {% set result = ref(result) %}
    {{ ref_format_results.append(result) }}
{% endfor %}

{% do log(ref_format_results, info=true) %}
```

Outputs:

```
['"my_db"."my_schema"."model_a"', '"my_db"."my_schema"."model_b"', '"my_db"."my_schema"."model_c"']
```

Comment: is there a way to get that last example (list) to not show the compiled version of ref()? i'm trying to replicate what you'd find in a list of model references pass to the relations parameter in dbt_utils.union_relations()

Comment: Technically the list in the last example is a list of Relations... it just gets logged as a string, which is the relation.identifier. So you should be able to use that list in a call to `union_relations`.

Comment: i would've thought the same except i keep getting a compilation error: dbt was unable to infer all dependencies for the model "request".
This typically happens when ref() is placed within a conditional block.

i'm unfamiliar with this error unfortunately.